# Simplest way to call an Objective C method from JavaScript (without plugins)?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, cordova

I know there are tons of such questions around but my question seems to differ a little bit from the rest. All I really want to do is to **call an objective C method from javascript**. I'm sure there's a way to do this without having to send paramters back and forth as suggested in many answers and [tutorials](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/calling-objective-c-function-from-javascript-in-ios-applications/). The purpose of this is for the users of my phonegap app to be able to click a HTML button to **hide the status bar**. For this to happen, I have to **find a way to tell my app to run my objective C method**: `HideStatusBar`

```
-(void) HideStatusBar {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```

I don't want to send any parameters, all I ask you to explain to me is how to tell obj c to make the method call from javascript. I know one solution is to **set parameters into the webviews address field** and then fetch via obj C but I'm sure there are easier solutions in my case.

I started off by **trying to write a phonegap plugin** but I *never got the "message accross" to "the other side"*, hence the method call in objective C never happened for some reason. I can post the code here if you like but I figured there must be a simpler solution.

Can anyone please explain to me **the simplest way to call a obj c method from within javascript**?

### Edit

I got this working but the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` only gets called when the webview is first loaded (as hinted in the title). This means that if i update the URL, the method does not get called. This is how I do it now:

**Javascript**

```
('#hideStatusBar').live('click',function(event) {
    window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', '/doc.html://hideStatusBar');
});
```

**Objective C**

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

//NSString *currentURL = request.URL.absoluteString;

if([request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"http://domain.com/doc.html://hideStatusBar"]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

As said, I want this method to be ran every time i update the URL of my HTML doc via javascript. Any further ideas?

Comment: Why exactly don't you want to pass parameters through a custom URL scheme?  You can't really do it any other way, UIWebView is sorta designed to *prevent* websites from calling code on the client.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought that was overkill in my case but if that's the only way, could you please provide me with an example? @iluvcapra

Answer (score 1):

the simplest and in my opinion wrong way to do it is to use the UIWebViewDelegate method shouldStartLoadWithRequest.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                                 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    //suppose you call yourApp://hideStatusBar
    if([request.url.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"yourApp://hideStatusBar"]){
        [self hideStatusBar];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES; 
}
```

From javascript

```
document.location = 'yourApp://hideStatusBar'
```

If you already use Cordova(Phonegap) you can build a simple plugin to avoid messing around with requests.

Comment: @elio.d (**Please see my edits to the post.**) This only works when the webview loads (as hinted in the method title), If i change the URL (without reloading the page) this objective c method does not get called. In other words, the whole purpose of this function is meaningless as I want the final result to be: user clicks on a div in the html doc and the status bar hides. I managed to create a phonegap plugin but was now trying your solution in a native app. As I said, the shouldStartLoadWithRequest method seems not be be the one in this case. Or am I mistaken somehow?

Comment: settings window.location.href = 'yourapp://yourFunction' trigger the method shouldStartLoadWithRequest, returning NO here make the webview discard this request but let you catch the request. This method always work. Looking at your edited post the url that you push is not the one I suggested..

Comment: Anyway in a native app you don't need all this stuff to hide the status bar

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial in the example has the right idea.  You do your own quickie URL scheme and serialize an argument (or whatever) into the URL.

If the user is browsing in a `UIWebView` that you control, you can patch into `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and use that to intercept when the user clicks on a link.  Your delegate then intercepts the URL and instead of letting the UIWebView change location, it dispatches execution of code on the delegate.